# readmore.js not working with bootstrap 3? (Django, jQuery, Bootstrap 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I have added readmore.js and imported jquery as seen below:

```
{% block head %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'location/readmore.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    $('.article').readmore();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The block head and endblock are part of the django framework

Below is my p.article:

```
<div class="row"><!--Row 2 start -->
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2> About this Location </h2>
        <p class="article">{{object.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't played with jQuery or javascript before. But i followed all the instructions and this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried placing the scripts at the end of the page, at the beginning. Nothing works

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: I get nothing. no Read more or anything. and when i inspect it there are no errors @sayse

Comment: those elements won't exist when code is run if that script tag precedes them in the page